# Probability density of data matrix

Tags: python, bash, gnuplot

I have a data file like this:

```
1 volume 318.31
2 volume 317.59
3 volume 316.71
4 volume 315.78
5 volume 315.07
6 volume 314.55
7 volume 314.38
8 volume 314.40
9 volume 314.86
10 volume 315.74
11 volume 316.83
12 volume 318.08
13 volume 319.44
14 volume 320.70
15 volume 322.04
16 volume 323.17
17 volume 323.77
18 volume 324.16
19 volume 324.02
20 volume 323.59
...
10000 volume 322.72
10001 volume 321.69
10002 volume 320.34
10003 volume 318.87
```

I would like to plot volumes vs probability like the following:
[image]

Is there any effective python module or bash shell+gnuplot function to deal with this problem?

Comment: You can use seaborn [kde plot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html)

Comment: @BinhThien, so you are talking about a histogram? i.e. putting your volumes values into bins of certain width and count the occurrences in each bin divided by to total number of data values? This can easily be done with gnuplot only. Check `help smooth frequency`. There are a lot of examples here on SO. Search for histogram, gnuplot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost any plotting package in python will allow you to generate a kde plot. If you are using pandas, then there is a simple solution to use the '**[density](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.density.html)**' keyword for the type of **plot** to generate.

I was not sure if the indices on the left were included in the file or not. Here is the solution if the **indices are not** in the data file.
I am assuming the file is named "**data.txt**".

```py
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep=' ', header=None, names=['string', 'volume'])
data['volume'].plot(kind = 'density')
```

If the **indices are included** in the data file, then you could modify the code above to look like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep=' ', header=None, names=['index', 'string', 'volume'])
data['volume'].plot(kind = 'density')
```

---

The following will ALL produce the same chart:

```py
data['volume'].plot(kind = 'density')
```

```py
data['volume'].plot.kde()
```

```py
data['volume'].plot.density()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I would like to extract the range of the highest density. Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: probably best to create a new question on stack overflow :)